# EntityFramework Core 2 : One to Many mapping using filtered list

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have entities that look like this:

```
class Parent1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

class Parent2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }

}


class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ParentType { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

basically in my case I have a Child table that contains the reference to different type of parents, but only one at a time. I am unable to understand how to create a `ModelBuilder` mapping to address this.

when I use `entity.HasMany(d => d.Children)` I don't see a way to map it with `ParentType = "Parent1"` and `ParentId = d.Id`

is it even possible in the EFCore 2.X

**Update 1:**

I have a constraint that I cannot change my table design that looks like this on the `child_table`

```
------------------------------------------------
| Id   |  Name  | Parent_Type  |  Parent_Id    |       
------------------------------------------------
|  1   | C1     | Parent1      | 1             |
|  2   | C2     | Parent2      | 1             |
|  2   | C3     | Parent2      | 1             |
|  2   | C4     | Parent1      | 1             |
|  2   | C5     | Parent2      | 1             |
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Create the relationship is "easy".. the issue is how are you going to load the Children of each parent type? I don't know if there's a way to do that automatically with EF/Navigation properties

Comment: Also, are the parents actually tables on the database? Or those are just your c# abstraction?

Comment: @jpgrassi: parents are actual tables

Comment: You can achieve the configuration to make it more or less work.. just do `WithMany(c => c.Children).WithOne().HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId)` on both entities (Parent1 and 2). But this will not help in querying.. when you do `context.Parent1.Include(p => p.Children).First()`, it will bring chindren from parent2 as well.. and I don't think there's an "automatic" way to solve it.

Comment: QueryFilters cannot help, because they don't work on navigation properties, and you can't also filter on Includes `context.Parent1.Include(p =>  p.Children.Where(c => c.ParentType == "Parent1"))`. This compiles but throws an exception at runtime. I typed on my phone, so excuse if code is wrong, but the idea is that.

Comment: Shortly - not possible. EF Core so far supports only physically enforced FK relationships.

Comment: @Kiran but then how does this db work at all? Is it SQL Server? Because you can't have an FK pointing to multiple tables like that.

Comment: @jpgrassi: there is no FK constraints at this time on the DB for this table

Answer (score 0):

You have to add both parent entities to the child entity and make the foreign-keys nullable.

Adjust your child-model to look like this

```
public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Parent1 Parent1 { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId1 { get; set; }
    public Parent2 Parent2 { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId2 { get; set; }
}
```

In you `DbContext` in the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method, do the following

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent1>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Children)
        .WithOne(c => c.Parent1)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId1);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent2>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Children)
        .WithOne(c => c.Parent2)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId2);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Child>();
    // more configuration
}
```

Now you can either have `Parent1` or `Parent2` or even both. In general your model doesn't make much sense like this but it would work. Maybe you need to rethink the model design you are trying to use.

You can find more samples on how to work with relationships in EF [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Comment: Thanks!, but I am not sure if this addresses my issue. I have updated my question with the Table structure for child, can you help me understand how to  map same column to multiple FK in your code

Comment: That doesn't work with EF because it's not SQL conform.